# Microsoft Graph API - OneNote - Create Page Issue - System.IO.Stream.get_ReadTimeout()

Tags: onenote, onenote-api, microsoft-graph-onenote

Tried Graph API directly for creating page, Is it the right way/possible or else we should use only HttpClient to create page.

Also I couldn't see C# code example for create page under request,
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/section-post-pages?view=graph-rest-1.0#request

**Errors**

> *InvalidOperationException: Timeouts are not supported on this stream.
> System.IO.Stream.get_ReadTimeout()*
> *JsonSerializationException: Error getting value from 'ReadTimeout' on 'System.IO.MemoryStream'.
> Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.ExpressionValueProvider.GetValue(object target)*

**Code**

```
var page = new OnenotePage
{
    Title = "Graph API Notes Page",
    Content = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Created Date - " + DateTime.Now))
};

await graphClient
        .Sites[siteId]
        .Onenote
        .Sections[sectionId]
        .Pages
        .Request()
        .AddAsync(page);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the below code to add content to OneNote page

```
 string notesContent = $"<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title>{NotebookTitle}</title></head><body>{NotebookContent}</body></html>";
                return await GraphClient.Me.Onenote.Sections[SectionId].Pages.Request().AddAsync(notesContent, "text/html");
```